# Parse .msg message using PHP

Tags: java, php, outlook, msg, pst

Is it possible to go inside a `.msg` file and get it's content (Header, Subject, To, From, email) using PHP?

Any easy to use libraries for it?

If not PHP, maybe Java?

Comment: Depends on software what created the .msg file. If it's "standard" linux, there are several php libraries that will read them. Just google for a list.

Comment: the question is tagged "outlook" so it's probably not about standard linux message. Anyhow, requests for libraries are off-topic on SO, and  question that doesn't know the language to implement in is "too broad" as a programming question.

Comment: Will your code be running a the machine where Outlook is installed?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko yes

Answer (score 0):

If Outlook is installed, you can use `Application.Session.OpenSharedItem` in the Outlook Object Model to open an MSG file.